# How many Odd and Even number are the in a array

Tags: javascript

I have created an Array with some numbers.
   I want to find out how many even, and how many odd numbers it is in
   this Array. I have to print it out like this: (this is just an example)

Even number: 6

Odd number: 7

I need to make a loop that count up how many it is off even and odd     numbers.

This is what I have so far

```
<script>

window.onload = run;

  var tall = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50];

  function run() {

    tall = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50];

    liste(tall);

  }

  function liste(arr) {

    var sumOdd = 0; // Odd 1, 3, 5 etc..
    var sumPar = 0; // Even 2, 4, 6 etc..

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
        sumPar += arr.length;
    }
      else {
        sumOdd += arr.length;
      }                                            // Even numbers                     // Odd numbers
      document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = "Partall:  " + sumPar + "<br />" + "Oddetall:  " + sumOdd;

  }

  }
}
</script>
```

Its something that is wrong here, and I dont know what.

Comment: `+= arr.length` makes no sense. You just want `+= 1`, or `++`.

Comment: Why are you adding the length of the array each time? If you want to count the number of elements that are odd or even, add one each time, if you want to add the value itself each time then do arr[i].

Comment: Don't you add the length of tall (so 10) every time you find a number? You would just need to add 1 every time you find one, not the length of the array.

Comment: I have been trying differents things. I started to try the arr[i], but the result was that they were summed together, and thats not what I wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were adding `arr.length` which is the array length. Instead you should simply increment the number

```js
var tall = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50];

liste(tall);

function liste(arr) {
  var sumOdd = 0;
  var sumPar = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
      sumPar++;
    } else {
      sumOdd++;
    }
  }
  
  console.log("Odd : " + sumOdd);
  console.log("Par : " + sumPar);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could iterate with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and count only the odds. For the rest just take the difference of the length of the array and the odds.

```js
var tall = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50],
    odd = tall.reduce(function (r, a) { return r + a % 2; }, 0),
    even = tall.length - odd;

console.log('odd', odd);
console.log('even', even);
```

Answer (score 0):

You always add the complete Length of the array to your variable

Try this instead of `sumPar += arr.length;`:

```
sumPar++;
```