# I have problems with finding how many odd numbers or even numbers are in an array

Tags: javascript

Given an array of integer numbers, compute how many values from the array are odd and how many of them are even.

Example: for array [1,4,7,11,12] the returned result will be:

Odd values: 3

Even values: 2

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302135/how-many-odd-and-even-number-are-the-in-a-array

Answer (score 2):

Use filter and check the length of the result array. Get the count of one of them(odd or even) and then to get the count of other subtract the length of found ones from length of array.

```js
let arr = [1,4,7,11,12];
let odd = arr.filter(x => x % 2).length
let even = arr.length - odd

console.log(`odd: ${odd}   even:${even}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = [1,4,7,11,12];

function countEven(array) {
  return array.filter(x => x % 2 === 0).length;
}

function countOdd(array) {
  return array.filter(x => x % 2 === 1).length;
}

console.log('Even', countEven(input));
console.log('Odd', countOdd(input));
```